# XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Library in the candidate Path

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, xgboost

I am encountering this problem when I was doing Spark distributed predict using sklearn XGBoost model loaded from joblib.

And here are the steps what I did:

**Step 1.** I ran sh build_python.sh which is located under xgboost directory in python `site-packages` path

**Step 2.** I zipped the xgboost directory to `xgboost.zip`

**Step 3.** I submitted a spark application using a command like `spark-submit *** --py-files xgboost.zip job.py` where `job.py` is the spark job entry and `sys.path.append("xgboost.zip")` code is included

Then, the error came out.

My own analysis:

**1.** I thought it is caused by the lack of `libxgboost.so`, but it is in the path of `xgboost.zip/xgboost/lib`.

**2.** Compilation is required before generating `xgboost.zip`. I copied config.mk to the xgboost path and tried to build it by running `make -j4`. However, I got an error like `No target specified to make ...Stop.`

Could anyone explain to me how to fix it? thanks in advance.

Here is the stack trace shot by me:
[image: stacktrace]

Comment: Please post edited error message as text.

Comment: Sorry, I can not paste the error stack trace here, as it happened in test env in my company. Please refer to the stack trace pic.